# Pass chef run list with parameters from cloudformation YAML script along with some values to override in attributes

Tags: chef-infra, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template in YAML and I need to execute Chef run list in the EC2 instance. For this I have passed the chef roles in the user data section as below -

```
UserData: !Base64 |
        {
        "Chef_RunList": "role[my_role_1],role[my_role_2]"
        }
```

Now, I need to pass a Cloudformation parameter , for ex. environment to this user data.
How do I join this and also use !Sub to replace the Environment variable.

For ex. below is the expectation -

```
UserData: !Base64 |
        {
          "Chef_RunList": "role[my_role_1],role[my_role_2]",
          "my_cookbook" : {
            "environment" : "!Sub Environment"
          }
        }
```

I want the environment variable to be overridden in Chef cookbook recipe by this value I pass from Cloudformation script.

Please help with the syntax of this user data section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference parameters in your `UserData` using `Sub` and `${Environment}`.

For example:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    Fn::Sub: |
        {
          "Chef_RunList": "role[my_role_1],role[my_role_2]",
          "my_cookbook" : {
            "environment" : "${Environment}"
          }
        }
```